# Kubeval Fails when running Kustomize test

Tags: kustomize

I'm having a test failure with my GitHub Action where I'm running this command against my kustomization.yaml file:

```
Run kubeval
ERR  - plant-simulator-deployment/templates/base/kustomization.yaml: Failed initalizing schema https://kubernetesjsonschema.dev/master-standalone-strict/kustomization-kustomize-v1beta1.json: Could not read schema from HTTP, response status is 404 Not Found
ERR  - plant-simulator-deployment/templates/dev/kustomization.yaml: Failed initalizing schema https://kubernetesjsonschema.dev/master-standalone-strict/kustomization-kustomize-v1beta1.json: Could not read schema from HTTP, response status is 404 Not Found
ERR  - plant-simulator-deployment/templates/production/kustomization.yaml: Failed initalizing schema https://kubernetesjsonschema.dev/master-standalone-strict/kustomization-kustomize-v1beta1.json: Could not read schema from HTTP, response status is 404 Not Found
```

Here is what I have in my kustomization.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Any ideas how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass some options to kubeval to ignore custom resources.

Either ignoring them all with `--ignore-missing-schemas` or listing the ones to ignore with `--skip-kinds`

From the [official doc](https://www.kubeval.com/#crds)